# Find the largest piece in UV-editor in Blender 2.73

Tags: python, uv

Is there any way of finding the largest UV-section in the UV-editor without manually comparing each piece next to each other? I want to select the piece that is the largest on either X, Y, or both axes.

Using Blender 2.73